# Json data: get one field

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON data in PHP:

```
"data": {
    "visible": false,
    "test": "test1",
    "gagnante": false,
    "create": "2013-05-17 21:53:39",
    "update": 1368820419
}
```

But, I want to to get the `create` field only. Like this:

```
"data": {
    "create": "2013-05-17 21:53:39"
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your question is very incomplete. What language are you working in. And more importantly, what have you tried on your own?

Comment: Ok, but which language are you using Sr?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? JSON is a format, not a language, so it can't be parsed on its own. What language are you working with?

Comment: Sorry, I'm usign PHP language

Comment: use `json_decode()`  and then fetch whatever you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode json and then parse it as you want

Something like

```
<?php
 $json  = ' "data": {
        "visible": false,
        "test": "test1",
        "gagnante": false,
        "create": "2013-05-17 21:53:39",
        "update": 1368820419
    }'

  $array = json_decode($json, true);
  echo $array['create'];
?>
```

Dont forget to include second parameter as `true` otherwise json_decode will return object instead of array

Answer (score 0):

```
$geolocatorrequest = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $urlreadystreetaddress . '&sensor=false';
$geolocatorresponse = file_get_contents($geolocatorrequest);
$geolocatordata = json_decode($geolocatorresponse, true);
```

Then you'll probably want to look and see what kind of structure you have.

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($geolocatorresponse) . "</pre>";
```

That will show you the structure so you know what array key path to follow for your value.
Since you failed to provide the url for the API you're using you just need to model after my example.

By the way:

```
json_decode($geolocatorresponse, true);
```

Adding true to that makes it give you the info in a PHP array format.  Otherwise you get it as objects, and you are on your own if you go with objects because I haven't delved into them yet.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your json codes require the outer { } to be considered valid JSON, now considering that you have the data in a file you could do:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('myFile.json'), true);     
$createField = $json['data']['create'];
// use array() instead of [] for php 5.3 or lower
$newJson = ["data" => ["create" => $createField]];
$newJson = json_encode($newJson);
file_put_contents('myNewFile.json', $newJson);
```

This will get the contents from the full json and convert it to an associative array then you can create a new array, pass the variables you want and encode the data in json format again, the last line saves the new json file

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you're after, but if you are running a relatively recent version of PHP, you can use json_encode and json_decode.

I'm running php 5.3.2 or something like that and here is how I did it....

ALSO -- don't listen to these other comments....objects are almost always better than arrays IMHO.

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";

$array['data'] = array(
    'visible'   => false,
    'test'      => 'test1',
    'gagnante'  => false,
    'create'    => '2013-05-17 21:53:39',
    'update'    => 1368820419
);

echo "From array to json...<br><br>";
$json =  json_encode($array);

echo "<br><br>{$json}<br><br>";

echo "<br><br>back out to an obj...<br><br>";

$obj = json_decode($json);

print_r($obj);

echo "<br><br>get just the field you're after<br><br>";

$new_array['data'] = array(
    'create' => $obj->data->create
);

echo "Back out to json....<br><br>";
echo json_encode($new_array);

echo "</pre>";
?>
```

this produces

```
From array to json...


{"data":{"visible":false,"test":"test1","gagnante":false,"create":"2013-05-17 21:53:39","update":1368820419}}



back out to an obj...

stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [visible] => 
            [test] => test1
            [gagnante] => 
            [create] => 2013-05-17 21:53:39
            [update] => 1368820419
        )

)


get just the field you're after

Back out to json....

{"data":{"create":"2013-05-17 21:53:39"}}
```